# Cakephp 3.0 : hasMany show key->value instead of array

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm using cakephp 3.0, and I have a 'users' table, and a 'profiles' table.
The users-table contains minimum information, username, e-mail, password.
The profiles-talbe contains detailed information : avatar, phone number, ...

I am able to link those 2 tables together with a hasMany association. And if I look at the output of a user, it shows the 'profiles' property, as an array, with an item for each profile information:

```
User (array)
   id    1
   username    admin
   email       admin@test.com
   password    ****
   -> created  (array)
   -> modified (array)
   -> profiles (array)
         -> 0  (array)
              id         1
              user_id    1
              key        avatar
              value      1.jpg
         -> 1  (array)
              id         2
              user_id    1
              key        phone
              value      555-1234
```

No it's still hard to get the Avatar. I'll have to go through all the profile-items to see which has the key 'avatar'.
What I'm looking for is something which will give this structure:

```
User (array)
   id    1
   username    admin
   email       admin@test.com
   password    ****
   -> created  (array)
   -> modified (array)
   -> profiles (array)
         avatar       1.jpg
         phone        555-1234
```

This would be much easier. Now I can just to User->profiles->avatar.

Is that possible?

Comment: Do you really need a `hasMany` relationship? Surely a `hasOne` relationship is more appropriate?

Comment: How it that? A user can have multple profile items.
Like an avatar or a phone or ...
I don't want to create a table with a column 'avatar' and a column 'phone, ...

Comment: Sorry, misread your data structure.

Comment: It's a lot more standard to have a "profiles" table with a hasOne association that has all the fields 'avatar', 'phone', `nickname` ...etc.  As opposed to having a single row for every possible option.  Just seems overkill doing it the way you're doing it, and it's making your resulting dataset more confusing too.

Comment: Is it? Because it is less flexible.
Let's say I have my whole site up-and-running and in production. And I feel the need to add a nickname to the profile. Not only do I need to update the table structure, but also the Entity and Table files.

Comment: EAV schemas have their pros and cons, generally they are useful when the attributes are constantly growing and/or shrinking, when they need to grow/shrink at runtime, or when your rows would otherwise be filled with lots of `NULL`s. Other than that I'd tend to call it an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using the [`Hash` utility](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/hash.html#Cake%5CUtility%5CHash::combine) to manipulate your returned array:-

```
$data['profiles'] = Cake\Utility\Hash::combine(
    $data['profiles'], 
    '{n}.key', 
    '{n}.value'
);
```

Comment: I'd suggest to put this in a [**result formatter**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-calculated-fields).